# Mongodb, search object in nested Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have these type of items on mongodb:

```
    {
    "_id": { "$oid" : "2" },
    "waypoints": [
        {
          "step": 0,
          "coordinates": [1,2]
        },
        {
          "step": 1,
          "coordinates": [1,3]
        },
        {
          "step": 2,
          "coordinates": [1,4]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to find [1,2] in the collection to retrieve waypoints.step and the _id, but the result is not what i expected.

I want to get:

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid" : "2" },
    "waypoints": [
        {
                "step": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

but i get:

```
{
    "_id": { "$oid" : "2" },
    "waypoints": [
        {
          "step": 0,
        },
        {
          "step": 1,
        },
        {
          "step": 2,
        }
    ]
}
```

what is the correct query to achieve what i want?

I know only the coordinates, i need to retrive _id of the object and the step corresponding to the coordinates I'm looking for.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by projecting data. The query should be :

```
db.collection.find({"_id": { "$oid" : "2" }},{waypoints : {$elemMatch : {coordinates:[1,2]}}})
```

For more information check [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) operator.

Comment: I know only the coordinates, i need to retrive _id and the step corresponding to the coordinates I'm looking for

Comment: I have updated my answer. This query will return the _id and step that belongs to the given coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're searching by `coordinates`, you can do it like this:

```
db.test.find({'waypoints.coordinates': [1,2]}, {'waypoints.$': 1})
```

In the projection, `$` represents the index of the `waypoints` array where the coordinate was found.

You'll get the `coordinates` value along with the `step`, but that's the best you can do:

```
{
  "_id": "2",
  "waypoints": [
    {
      "step": 0,
      "coordinates": [
        1,
        2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```