# Find objects in nested array, mongodb, compass

Tags: mongodb, compass

I'm using Mongodb database and Compass tool to visualize my data.
My collection called 'ProbCancer' looks like that:

```
probCancers: [
        cases: [
                {
                   case: {
                   bi: Number,
                   age: Number,
                 },
                   level: Number,
                   _id: false,
                }
              ]
            ]
```

Since I have many objects in the `cases` array, it's hard to analyze them. I want to only find objects that have level = -1. Is there any way to do this query in compass? Giving the `query` parameter in `db.probCancers.find(query);` could be helpful for me as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it in mongoDB shell from this link: [Mongodb, search object in nested Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047314/mongodb-search-object-in-nested-array), but I don't know why it doesn't work in compass version 1.11.2.

There is a solution by defining the `query` parameter like that: `{cases: {$elemMatch: { level: -1}}}`, and to prevent getting the full `cases` array we should specify the `projection` field. It's the same as the `query` field. But this solution returns the first object in the `cases` array that matches with `level = -1`.

So, this is the result:

```
db.probCancer.find({cases: {$elemMatch: { level: -1}}}, 
                   {cases: {$elemMatch: { level: -1}}}
                  );
```

In mongoDB, to do queries in a nested array, the array must be flatted. Then the query would be done in the resulted flatted array. To do so, we need to use pipeline aggregation see [the link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

And this code will give us the wanted result:

```
db.probCancer.aggregate([ { $unwind : "$cases" }, { $match : {"cases.level":-1}} ]);
```

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) projections are not supported in Compass. There is an open [tracker](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-2181) for the issue. (I don't have enough reputation to comment on Bentaiba's answer.)

**Edit1:**
The issue above was closed (fixed) Sep 27 2019.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying:

```
db.ProbCancer.find( { "cases.level" : -1 } )
```

Or you can use **$all** you can find more infos in the official documentations of mongodb : [Link to documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/)

Comment: `db.ProbCancer.find( { "cases.level" : -1 } )` won't work only if I add the index of the array, for example `db.ProbCancer.find( { "cases.12.level" : -1 } )` gives me all documents were `cases[12].level = -1`.